# Difficulties with awk sub command output when there is a + sign in the last field

Tags: awk, character

folks:

I am having a problem with the awk sub command when passing it a string that contains the + symbol in the last field.  I am trying to output all but the last field in the record without the trailing field separator.  For example:

```
echo "dog cat fish hamster" | awk 'sub(FS $NF, x)'
```

This produces the desired output of "dog cat fish"

```
echo "dog cat fish +hamster" | awk 'sub(FS $NF, x)'
```

This produces what appears to be no output.

```
echo "dog +cat fish hamster" | awk 'sub(FS $NF, x)'
```

This also produces the expected output of "dog +cat fish"

I am using awk to parse a configuration file with one or more source directories and a single destination directory for use in transfering files with scp.  Some of the destination directories have a +, such as **/app/tgv+/in** and I am unable to change the mount points because of legacy code.  The problem only seems to occur when the + appears in the last field.  I would be very grateful if you could help me determine if I have done something wrong or if this is simply a problem with the awk string parser.  Thanks so much for any assistance.

DGC

Comment: Your `sub` function looks weird. You want to remove `+` or the whole word containing `+`?

Comment: The expected behavior is to output all but the last field of input.  This works until regex special symbols get into the input as the answer shows below. Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the first argument of `sub()` is supposed to be a regular expression. This doesn't bother in most cases of matching absolute strings. But in your case
`FS $NF` will become `+hamster` which will be treated as a regular expression and thus won't get matched with anything and thus, anything won't get printed.

Even if you use something like `{1}hamster` instead of `+hamster`, there won't be any output.

A better approach will be to change the way. A simple method can be

```
echo "dog cat fish +hamster" | awk 'NF--'
```

Comment: +1! And there is another problem with the `awk` script in question. See `echo "dog cat hamster fish hamster" | awk 'sub(FS $NF, x)'`, result: `dog cat fish hamster`.

Comment: I found my particular approach while searching for a means to print all but the last field of each line.  Your response for an alternate means does work, but my approach was offered as a means to produce the output WITHOUT a trailing field separator also being output.  I have already resorted to the NF-- method and it functions correctly.  I simply hadn't expected that awk would turn the values of internal variables into regular expressions.  Thank you so much for taking the time to explain.

Comment: The duplication issues would also be a problem, except that the configuration file is manually created and contains file systems mount points that are not duplicated and this doesn't create an issue.  The issue came about when a destination mount point contained + in the path itself and I wasn't able to have the programmers change it.  Thanks for pointing out another possible gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

`NF--` has the risk of triggering the `negative NF` fatal error :

> ```
> echo ' abc def 123 456 \n\n' | mawk NF--
> ```

```
abc def 123
mawk: run time error: negative value assigned to NF
        FILENAME="-" FNR=2 NR=2

mawk2: run time error: negative value assigned to NF
        FILENAME="-" FNR=2 NR=2

gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=2) fatal: NF set to negative value

nawk: cannot set NF to a negative value
 input record number 2, file 
 source line number 1
```

To mitigate that risk without having to use `if-then-else` or `? :`-ternary operator, do either of these instead :

```
echo ' abc def 123 456 \n\n' |
```

> ```
> mawk 'NF -= !!NF'
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> gawk 'NF && --NF'
> ```

```
abc def 123
```